# Add row to Access Table from DataTable

Tags: c#, database, datatable, oledb

I've used this code to create me a `DataTable` from my Access table.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
...
using (OleDbConnection oledbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connection))
{
   oledbConnection.Open();
   using (OleDbCommand oledbCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Student", oledbConnection))
   {
       using (OleDbDataAdapter oledbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oledbCommand))
       {
          oledbDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
       }
   }
}
```

I later changed the datatable by inserting a new row with this code.

```
DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
dataRow["FirstName"] = "John";
dataRow["LastName"] = "Connor";
dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
dataTable.GetChanges();
```

How can I bring this change in my access database?
Is correct the following code?

```
using (OleDbConnection oledbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
   OleDbDataAdapter oledbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
   oledbDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(queryString, oledbConnection);
   OleDbCommandBuilder oledbCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oledbDataAdapter);
   connection.Open();
   oledbDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = oledbCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand(true);
   oledbDataAdapter.InsertCommand = oledbCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
   oledbDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = oledbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
   oledbDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
   connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to reopen the connection and do an insert into that database. The SQL could look something like this:

```
string sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO Students(FirstName,LastName) VALUES({0},{1})", "John", "Connor")
```

Comment: but you can't copy my DataTable directly into the Access file?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I don't believe it is possible without reopening the connection explicitly.

Comment: Could you help me or suggest a method to copy the entire dataTable? It's very important.

Comment: This link [OleDbDataAdapter.Update()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2(v=vs.110).aspx) may be what you're looking for. You should be able to pass in your modified datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert it in `Access DB` by using `insert query` after the code you typed for Row inserttion in `DataTable`.

This is because `DataTable` is a saved in memory and is a `Disconnected Architecture` (means it fetches data from DB and no longer connected with it).

Comment: but you can't copy my DataTable directly into the Access file?